# Receiving explicit intents while activity is in the foreground

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

My app has one activity and one service. The service starts a foreground notification that has an action button that in some situations needs to tell the activity to do something besides just coming back to the front. It uses the Extras to indicate this something.

My issues are that I can't find any documentation on how to receive explicit intents other than through the "bundle" passed to `onCreate()` which isn't usually called because the activity could already be created.

How do you receive an intent after onCreate()?

### Notification code snippet:

```kotlin
    val actionIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    actionIntent.action = actionText
    actionIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
    val pendingActionIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, actionIntent, 0)
    
    val actionCancel: NotificationCompat.Action = NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_cancel_black_24dp,
                                                                                    actionText,
                                                                                    pendingActionIntent).build()
    
    val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notification_title))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_24dp)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .addAction(actionCancel)
            .setContentText(text)
    
    startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `onNewIntent()`. If the activity already exists, and an `Intent` is bringing it back to the foreground, that `Intent` is delivered to `onNewIntent()`.

Comment: Is this only called if onCreate() isn't? I.e. do I need to handle the intent in both places?

Comment: @kkemper: "do I need to handle the intent in both places?" -- typically, yes. A common approach is to have a single function that you call from `onCreate()` (passing `getIntent()`) and `onNewIntent()` (passing the `Intent` given to `onNewIntent()`), to reduce code duplication.